# Count Trailing and Leading NA for each vector

Tags: r, vector, na

I have some vectors in the following format

```
    v1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,10,10,10,10)
    v2 <- c(NA,NA, 3, 3, 3,NA,NA)
    v3 <- c( 5, 5, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
```

For each vector I want to calculate how many leading NAs and trailing NAs.

```
    For v1, LeadNA = 3, TrailNA = 0
    For v2, LeadNA = 2, TrailNA = 2
    For v3, LeadNA = 0, TrailNA = 5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) Cumsum** - An option would be to create a logical vector with `cumsum` on the presence of non-NA elements and get the `sum` (`base R` - No packages used)

```
f1 <- function(vec, trail = FALSE) {
  if(trail) {
     vec <- rev(vec)
    }
    sum(!cumsum(!is.na(vec)))
 }

f1(v1)
#[1] 3
f1(v1, TRUE)
#[1] 0

sapply(mget(paste0("v", 1:3)), f1)
#  v1 v2 v3 
# 3  2  0 
sapply(mget(paste0("v", 1:3)), f1, TRUE)  
#  v1 v2 v3 
#  0  2  5
```

---

**2 rle** - Another `base R` option is `rle` (No packages are used)

```
with(rle(is.na(v2)), lengths[values & seq_along(values) %in% c(1, length(values))])
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper over `which.max`:

```
leading.nas <- function(x) {
  if (length(x) == 0) {
   0L 
  }
  else {
    which.min(!is.na(x)) - 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Could also use `which.min`

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be similar to @Bulat's solution

```
count_nas <- function(x) {
  nas <- is.na(x)

  if (sum(nas) == length(x)) {
    warning('all elements were NA')
    return(c(start_na = NA_integer_, end_na = NA_integer_))
  }

  c(start_na = which.min(nas) - 1,
    end_na = which.min(rev(nas)) - 1)
}

count_nas(v1)
#start_na   end_na 
#       3        0 

sapply(list(v1,v2,v3), count_nas)
#         [,1] [,2] [,3]
#start_na    3    2    0
#end_na      0    2    5
```

As far as performance, this is the fastest method with @akrun's methods being in the ballpark.

```
v_test3 <- sample(10000)
v_test3[c(1:3, 9998:10000)] <- NA_integer_

Unit: microseconds
             expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
     akrun_cumsum   175.7   182.15   193.580   186.55   200.80   354.7   100
        akrun_rle   168.6   199.25   210.635   209.25   221.00   289.3   100
    g_grothen_zoo  1848.5  1904.45  2008.994  1941.40  2001.35  4799.6   100
 g_grothen_reduce 12467.3 12888.10 14174.157 13445.15 15054.35 28241.6   100
        www_rleid  5357.2  5439.40  5741.471  5517.15  5947.15  8470.4   100
   bulat_and_cole    63.5    66.45    73.681    71.25    75.75    96.9   100
```

Code for reproducibility:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(zoo)
library(data.table)

v_test3 <- sample(10000)
v_test3[c(1:3, 9998:10000)] <- NA_integer_

count_nas <- function(x) {
  nas <- is.na(x)

  if (sum(nas) == length(x)) {
    warning('all elements were NA')
    return(c(start_na = NA_integer_, end_na = NA_integer_))
  }

  c(start_na = which.min(nas) - 1,
    end_na = which.min(rev(nas)) - 1)
}

countNA <- function(x) {
  len <- function(fromLast = FALSE) length(na.locf(x, fromLast = fromLast))
  if (all(is.na(x))) c(left = NA, right = NA)
  else length(x) - c(left = len(), right = len(TRUE))
}

f1 <- function(vec, trail = FALSE) {
  if(trail) {
    vec <- rev(vec)
  }
  sum(!cumsum(!is.na(vec)))
}

count_fun <- function(x){
  y <- rleid(x)
  z <- split(x, y)[c(1, length(unique(y)))]
  ans <- sapply(z, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  return(unname(ans))
}

countNA2 <- function(x) {
  f <- function(x) sum(Reduce(all, is.na(x), acc = TRUE))
  if (all(is.na(x))) c(left = NA, right = NA)
  else c(left = f(x), right = f(rev(x)))
}

microbenchmark(
  akrun_cumsum = {
    f1(v_test3, TRUE)
    f1(v_test3, FALSE)
  }
  , 
  akrun_rle = {
    with(rle(is.na(v_test3)), lengths[values & seq_along(values) %in% c(1, length(values))])
  }
  ,
  g_grothen_zoo = {
    countNA(v_test3)
  }
  ,
  g_grothen_reduce = {
    countNA2(v_test3)
  }
  ,
  www_rleid = {
    count_fun(v_test3)
  }
  ,
  bulat_and_cole = {
    count_nas(v_test3)
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) na.locf** Remove the leading NAs using `na.locf` and determine the difference in length between the original and reduced vector.  Do the same for the trailing NAs.  It is not clear what should be returned if the input vector is empty or all NAs so we return NA for both left and right.

```
library(zoo)

countNA <- function(x) {
  len <- function(fromLast = FALSE) length(na.locf(x, fromLast = fromLast))
  if (all(is.na(x))) c(left = NA, right = NA)
  else length(x) - c(left = len(), right = len(TRUE))
}

countNA(v1)
##  left right 
##     3     0 

countNA(v2)
##  left right 
##     2     2 

countNA(v3)
##  left right 
##     0     5
```

It would also be possible to use `na.fill` to perform this calculation.

**2) Reduce** A second approach is to use `Reduce`.  It gives the same answer. No packages are used.

```
countNA2 <- function(x) {
  f <- function(x) sum(Reduce(all, is.na(x), acc = TRUE))
  if (all(is.na(x))) c(left = NA, right = NA)
  else c(left = f(x), right = f(rev(x)))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function returns two numbers. The first is the count of leading `NA`. The second is the count of trailing `NA`. It requires the `rleid` function from the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

count_fun <- function(x){
  y <- rleid(x)
  z <- split(x, y)[c(1, length(unique(y)))]
  ans <- sapply(z, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  return(unname(ans))
}

count_fun(v1)
# [1] 3 0

count_fun(v2)
# [1] 2 2

count_fun(v3)
# [1] 0 5
```